# Unknown threads in Java and JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have 5 threads in my application.
I am suprise to have so many of them because I though I will have only a main thread and a JavaFX thread for the UI.

Could you tell me what are the 3 other threads ?

```
Thread [main]
Deamon Thread [QuantumRenderer-0]
Deamon Thread [Thread-1]
Thread [JavaFX Application Thread]
Thread [JavaFX-Launcher]
```

Thank you in advance,

Edit: 
My environment is Eclipse Luna. I am running the application in Eclipse debug.
I have other thread that I am starting myself that I am not writting in the list.

Comment: Could you give us some information about your environment? What is the structure of your system? Are you starting any threads inside of your code? How are you running your application?

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem?  Do you have reason to believe that the problem is somehow caused by the extra threads?  Most JVMs use threads for things like JIT compilation and garbage collection.

Comment: No, everything works fine. I am just documenting my software. It is more curiosity than a real need.
My environment is Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread [main] - The thread that invoked `main()`, essentially the thread that started your java application. Every java application has this thread at the very least.

Deamon Thread [QuantumRenderer-0] - Extract from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/architecture/jfxpub-architecture.htm) documentation

> Quantum Toolkit ties Prism and Glass Windowing Toolkit together and
>   makes them available to the JavaFX layer above them in the stack. It
>   also manages the threading rules related to rendering versus events
>   handling.

Deamon Thread [Thread-1] - The name suggests that it might be a user thread or some internal thread, someone just forgot to properly name it, as far as I'm concerned `Thread-#` is the default name.

Thread [JavaFX Application Thread] - This is the JavaFX UI Thread, all running JavaFX applications will have this. Any changes to JavaFX UI must be done on this thread

Thread [JavaFX-Launcher] - The 'main' thread doesn't start JavaFX applications directly. They are instead started on this thread.

Comment: Thank you, very useful for my documentation !